# Amazon Athena : HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR: name expected at the position 22 of [...] but ' ' is found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless, amazon-athena

I use a serverless file + CloudFormation to create a table on the AWS Athena service.

My serverless.yml:

```
...
CardBulkWorkgroup:
  Type: AWS::Athena::WorkGroup
  Properties:
    Name: ${opt:stage}-${opt:client}-CardBulk
    WorkGroupConfiguration:
      ResultConfiguration:
        OutputLocation: s3://${lower:${opt:stage}}-${lower:${opt:client}}-card-bulk-athena-result

CardBulkDatabase:
  Type: AWS::Glue::Database
  Properties:
    CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
    DatabaseInput:
      Name: ${lower:${opt:stage}}_${lower:${opt:client}}_bulkcard

CardBulkTable:
  Type: AWS::Glue::Table
  Properties:
    CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
    DatabaseName: !Ref CardBulkDatabase
    TableInput:
      Name: card
      StorageDescriptor:
        Columns:
          - Name: cardId
            Type: int
          - Name: metadata
            Type: struct<orderId:string, convertVirtualToPhysicalErrors:string>
          - Name: orderId
            Type: string
          - Name: errors
            Type: string
        Location: s3://${lower:${opt:stage}}_${lower:${opt:client}}-files/cards
        InputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
        OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
        SerdeInfo:
          SerializationLibrary: org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe
          Parameters:
            "serialization.format": "1"

CardBulkAthenaBucketResult:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
    BucketName: ${lower:${opt:stage}}-${lower:${opt:client}}-card-bulk-athena-result
...
```

When I deploy my stack, the database ***dev_connect_bulkcard*** and my table ***card***  are created correctly.

The issue:

With my **API**, when I want to retrieve data from ***card*** table from my ***dev_connect_bulkcard*** database, I get this error.

> "HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR: Error: name expected at the position 22 of
> 'struct<orderId:string, convertVirtualToPhysicalErrors:string>' but '
> ' is found.

But, if I delete the ***card*** table directly from the AWS console (from Athena Service) and, generate it with this query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `card`(
  `cardid` int COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `orderid` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `metadata` struct<orderid:string,convertvirtualtophysicalerrors:string> COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `errors` array<string> COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://my-bucket-files/cards'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='false', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1627378097')
```

It's work, I can return the data from the card table with my **API**.

Do you have any idea why I have to delete my table manually and then recreate it to get the results back please?

Thanks in advance,

EDIT: Solution by `Prabhakar Reddy`:

> The error is due to the space present in the column metadata. Remove
> the space between orderId and convertVirtualToPhysicalErrors . Athena
> will not accept space as a special character in it's column name.
> Refer this for more information.

Comment: The error indicates that your column has a space in it. Can you remove space in "struct<orderId:string, convertVirtualToPhysicalErrors:string>" in your template and try again?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Thanks a lot ! You're right, the error is comming from this line from my serverless file:

`Type: struct<orderId:string, convertVirtualToPhysicalErrors:string>`

It's resolved ! :)

Comment: I have added answer. Please mark it as answered it it helped.

Comment: Thank's you so much @PrabhakarReddy ! :)

And thank's for the documentation :) !

I accepted you'r answer but, i can't up vote, i have this message:

**Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is due to the space present in the column `metadata`. Remove the space  between `orderId` and `convertVirtualToPhysicalErrors` . Athena will not accept space as a special character in it's column name. Refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-databases-columns-names.html) for more information.